# How to remove duplicate List items having the same Map Key in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list where I add Map values when the user clicks a button. The user is presented with 3 buttons, each button has the same questionId (such as 3) but the answerValue is different for each button. Everytime a user clicks one button, a Map with question id and answerValue is added to a list.
My list looks like this below if the user clicked all three buttons having the same Question Id:

```
{{questionId: 4, answerValue : 8}, {questionId: 4, answerValue : 7}, {questionId: 4, answerValue : 8}}
```

so the problem I am facing now is I have duplicate items as you can see from above. Instead of replacing the answerValue, the list is adding more and more items as many times the user is clicking the buttons. What i want to achieve here is if the questionId is same, the list should replace that item instead of creating a new list entry. I tried using set() and other answers found in stackoverflow but most of them is just for a single list item and I could not achieve what i was looking for. Check below for code:

```
//This generates a map
    var map = new QuesNValues(questionId: widget.ques.questions[widget.index].question.questionOptions[i].questionId, questionOptionId: val).toJson(); 

// Output: {questionId: 4, questionOptionId: 9}
```

This map is then added to a list:

```
selectedQuesValuesList.add(map);
```

I've tried using for statements for items in list but i simple could not make it work. I just need the list to replace values having the same questionId instead of creating new items.

Answer (score -1):

Before adding a response to your list, you can clean it :

```
selectedQuesValuesList.removeWhere((m) => m.questionId == id);
```

Comment: I get an error here. ''m.questionId''
Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' has no instance getter 'questionId'.

Comment: selectedQuesValuesList.removeWhere((m) => m["questionId"] == id);